# How to sync tags between posts that are linked through Posts 2 Posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, sync

I am faced with a thorny problem and can't seem to find the solution in the wealth of community knowledge on the web. I have two custom posts types "Person" and "Activities". I use posts 2 posts (plugin) to link Persons with their various Activities and vice-versa.

I have Taxonomies which apply to Activities. They describe areas of practice and interest. Using them, I'd like to be able to get a list of Persons who partake in Activities tagged with "Cranes", for example. Where "Cranes" is part of an Area of interest in my tag-like custom taxonomy.

I suspect the most practical way to go about it would be to apply the taxonomy to both post-types and keep them in sync from the linked Activities to the Persons automatically. Is there a way to do that?

Kind regards,
Evren

EDIT: My p2p_register_connection_type is as follows

```
function ghunige_connection_types() {
    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
        'name' => 'profile_to_activity',
        'from' => 'ghunige_profile',
        'to' => 'ghunige_activity',
        'reciprocal' => true,
        'title' => array( 'from' => __('Participates in', 'ghunige_dir_domain'), 'to' => __('Participants', 'ghunige_dir_domain') )

    ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 solutions for you problem. The first is rely on P2P functions like `each_connected` (see [this](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected#using-each_connected-multiple-times) as example) and retrieve the connected 'Person' after running a taxonomy query for 'Activities'.

Maybe this solution can be easier, faster and straightforward.

Second solution is what you says in your question: apply the taxonomy to both post types.

To sync taxonomy terms you can hook into action 'added_term_relationship' action

```
   add_action( 'added_term_relationship', 'sync_my_tax', 20, 2);

   function sync_my_tax ( $object_id, $tt_id ) { 
     $post = get_post($object_id);
     if ( $post->post_type == 'activities' ) {
       global $wpdb;
       $taxonomy = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT taxonomy FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = " . $tt_id);
       if ( $taxonomy != 'your_taxonomy' ) return; // put here your tax name
       $related = p2p_type( 'person_to_activities' )->get_related( $post );  
       if ( ! empty($related) ) { foreach ( $related as $person ) {
         $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->term_relationships, array( 'object_id' => $person->ID, 'term_taxonomy_id' => $tt_id ) );
       } }
     }
   }
```

I cannot assure `p2p_type` call in this code is right because you don't post your `p2p_register_connection_type()` call.

Also note, that all the code is **untested**, so don't use on production site before you have fully tested it.

Comment: I can't seem to adapt the code to my p2p_register_connection_type. Neither can I find the 'added_term_relationship' hook in the documentation. Who adds it: Wordpress or P2P?

Comment: @Evren when you need info on code, best documentation is code itself. See [wp-includes/taxonomy.php line 2210](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2210)

Comment: Lesson learned, @G. M. I think I understand what the above code does and how. I have double, triple and quadruple checked my variables and tested, tested, tested the code. It doesn't work, yet.

I have a couple follow-up questions:

- What is the taxonomy's name? Is it the slug, the query string or the proper name that goes in register_taxonomy()?
- Is there a "taxonomy" table in the DB or is it supposed to be the name of the taxonomy also? I don't have access to our database at this time.

Comment: @Evren taxonomy's name is the one goes in `register_taxonomy()`. Taxonomy in wordpress are handled with 3 different tables: `$wpdb->terms`, `$wpdb->term_taxonomy` (the 1 save terms data, the second the terms related to taxonomy). Then there is the `$wpdb->term_relationships` the contains the taxonomy - posts associations. I can't test the code because I've no P2P installed, so I can't help you more than this...